Is there any way to play audio in Apple Watch through built-in speaker?
I'm building a watchOS app that plays audio through the built-in speaker.
I am trying with the simulator - is it an issue with the simulator?

In general, if the user has previously selected a Bluetooth route or if AirPods or other W1-equipped Bluetooth headphones are nearby, the system picks the audio route automatically without displaying a picker view to the user. If no applicable Bluetooth route is selected (either automatically or by the user), the system passes an error to the completion handler.

The above is what Apple states here, but it does not clearly mention that playing audio on the built-in speaker is not supported.
I've tried many ways with AVPlayer, AVAudioPlayer, and WKAudioFilePlayerItem, but nothing works.
